# If I update Xcode 3.2.5 to Xcode 4, would this remove old iOS SDK's?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm currently building a web app, which is built with Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS 4.2. If I update to Xcode 4, can I still build for iOS 4.2 and target devices iPhone 3GS?

Comment: No it doesn't delete old versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can still build for iOS 4.2 or 3GS - no problem. All you need to set is the deployment target to 4.2 and you can generate a build for iOS 4.x without any problems.